# MemoryError using CVS2SVN

Tags: python, svn, cvs2svn

I'm trying to migrate a CSV repository to SVN using csv2svn. After dealing with some errors during the first pass (CollectRevsPass), i'm in the fourth step and this error appears:

```
...
c:\Users\Andres\Desktop\copa\copa\proyectosAMEG\JGA\KnapsackJG2A\src\operators\K
napsackSelection.java,v
Done
Time for pass1 (CollectRevsPass): 68.47 seconds.
----- pass 2 (CleanMetadataPass) -----
Converting metadata to UTF8...
Done
Time for pass2 (CleanMetadataPass): 0.437 seconds.
----- pass 3 (CollateSymbolsPass) -----
Checking for forced tags with commits...
Done
Time for pass3 (CollateSymbolsPass): 0.015 seconds.
----- pass 4 (FilterSymbolsPass) -----
Filtering out excluded symbols and summarizing items...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn", line 70, in <module>
    svn_main(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]), sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\main.py", line 113, in svn_main
    main(progname, run_options, pass_manager)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\main.py", line 96, in main
    pass_manager.run(run_options)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\pass_manager.py", line 181, in run
    the_pass.run(run_options, stats_keeper)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\passes.py", line 505, in run
    revision_collector.process_file(cvs_file_items)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\checkout_internal.py", line 615, in process_file
    _Sink(self, cvs_file_items),
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\rcsparser.py", line 68, in parse
    return selected_parser().parse(file, sink)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_rcsparse\common.py", line 477, in parse
    self.parse_rcs_deltatext()
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_rcsparse\common.py", line 450, in parse_rcs_deltatext
    self.sink.set_revision_info(revision, log, text)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\checkout_internal.py", line 539, in set_revision_info
    text_record, self._rcs_stream.get_text()
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\checkout_internal.py", line 601, in _writeout
    self._delta_db[text_record.id] = text
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\indexed_database.py", line 94, in __setitem__
    s = self.serializer.dumps(item)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\Downloads\cvs2svn-2.4.0.tar\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\cvs2svn-2
.4.0\cvs2svn_lib\serializer.py", line 138, in dumps
    return marshal.dumps(zlib.compress(self.wrapee.dumps(object), 9))
MemoryError
```

I checked and there is enough free memory, when this error appear. Just before the Error appears, the process 'python' increaces a lot the use of memory.

Does Some one know what can I do?

- CVS2SVN 2.4
- Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

This error can also indicate that the process has run out of virtual address space.  If you are running cvs2svn in 32-bit mode, then the process only has something like 2 GiB or 4 GiB of addresses that it can use, regardless of whether the computer has free RAM.  If this is the case, try running the program in 64-bit mode.

If you are already running in 64-bit mode, then try increasing RAM or swap space or running the program on a beefier computer.

Comment: Hi @mhagger, when the error appears the computer seems to have enough free memory, do you know if there is some command to assign more memory space to the procedure? I will also try your answer